# Process file or stdin

Tags: c, file, stdin

I'm creating a little program which processes an archive; which is runned like this:

```
"./program file.txt".
```

If no second parameter is found, it will process from stdin

```
"cat file.txt | ./program"
```

But inside the code... I know I can do this:

```
if (argc==2){
    FILE* archive = argv[1];
    function_1(archive);
    function_2(archive);
    ...
    function_n(archive);
else{
    function_1(stdin);
    function_2(stdin);
    ...
    function_n(stdin);
}
```

But is there anyway I can do it this way?

```
file* archive;
if (argc==2){
    archive = argv[1];
else{
    archive = stdin;
}
function_1(archive);
function_2(archive);
...
function_n(archive);
```

Because I would like to write less code!

Answer (score 2):

Since `stdin` is a variable of type `FILE *`, you can do exactly that:

```
FILE *archive;
if (argc==2){
    archive = fopen(argv[1], "r");
else{
    archive = stdin;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `archive` with a ternary operator:

```
FILE* archive = (argc == 2) ? fopen(args[1], "r") : stdin;
```

Of course, you have to close it at the end with a check as well.